# Extracting ZIP files in a directory that doesn't exist

Tags: ruby

I want to extract one single content type file from a ZIP package into a directory that doesn't yet exist. My code so far:

```
  require 'zip'

  Dir.mkdir 'new_folder'
  #I create the folder

  def unzip_file (file_path, destination)
  Zip::File.open(file_path) { |zip_file| 
  zip_file.glob('*.xml'){ |f| #I want to extract .XML files only
      f_path = File.join(Preprocess, f.name) 
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path)) 
      puts "Extract file to %s" % f_path
      zip_file.extract(f, f_path) 
  }
}
end
```

The folder gets successfully created, but no extraction is done at any directory. I suspect that there is something wrong within the working directory. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you forgot to call your `unzip` method to begin with...

Nevertheless, this is how I would do this:

```
require 'zip'

def unzip_file (file_path, destination)
  Zip::File.open(file_path) do |zip_file| 
    zip_file.each do |f| #I want to extract .XML files only
      next unless File.extname(f.name) == '.xml'
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination) 
      f_path = File.join(destination, File.basename(f.name)) 
      puts "Extract file to %s" % f_path
      zip_file.extract(f, f_path) 
    end
  end
end

zip_file = 'random.zip' # change this to zip file's name (full path or even relative path to zip file)
out_dir = 'new_folder' # change this to the name of the output folder
unzip_file(zip_file, out_dir) # this runs the above method, supplying the zip_file and the output directory
```

---

**EDIT**

Adding an additional method called `unzip_files` that call `unzip_file` on all zipped files in a directory.

```
require 'zip'

def unzip_file (file_path, destination)
  Zip::File.open(file_path) do |zip_file| 
    zip_file.each do |f| #I want to extract .XML files only
      next unless File.extname(f.name) == '.xml'
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)
      f_path = File.join(destination, File.basename(f.name)) 
      puts "Extract file to %s" % f_path
      zip_file.extract(f, f_path) 
    end
  end
end

def unzip_files(directory, destination)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)
  zipped_files = File.join(directory, '*.zip')
  Dir.glob(zipped_files).each do |zip_file|
    file_name = File.basename(zip_file, '.zip') # this is the zipped file name
    out_dir = File.join(destination, file_name)
    unzip_file(zip_file, out_dir)
  end
end

zipped_files_dir = 'zips' # this is the folder containing all the zip files
output_dir = 'output_dir' # this is the main output directory
unzip_files(zipped_files_dir, output_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I assign `zip_file` with any .ZIP file?

Comment: If you have a single Zip file, change the value of the variable `zip_file` to the name of zip file (either full path or relative path)...

Comment: If you have multiple zip files that you want to run this on, let me know and I can update the code for you... (also if so, are all the zip files in a single directory?)...

Comment: Exactly, i have different . ZIP files (with different names) and they are all in the same directory.

Comment: Apparently there is something wrong in the second method because no extraction is done. The new directory created is empty, with no .XML files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125707/discussion-between-ismail-m-and-topa-14).